# Releasing WinForm Program Updates

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-installer, release

I'd like to release some updates for a WinForm program, but to date I have simply released an all-new compile.  People have to un-install the old version and install the new version.

**EDIT: I'm using an auto-generated InstalWizard.  It preserves my file strucutre and places the [PrimaryProgramOutput] in a particular directory.  I forget what this is called.**

I bet there's a way to get around this, but I don't know what it's called.  As you may guess, searches for "updates" "new version" "install" and the other obvious things I've tried have generated an impressive number of irrelevant results.  >_<

I suspect this process has a particular name, which should point me in the right direction, but if it doesn't please link to a tutorial or something.

Comment: +1, I've been looking for this myself

Comment: What installer are you using? I am unsing Inno Setup, and to update one of my programs, you simply install the new version (execute the new "setup.exe"). You do *not* need to uninstall the previous version, unless in very rare cases (e.g. if the file structure in C:\Program Files\My App has changed in the new version).

Comment: Oh right.
I'm using a Windows Installer.  I don't remember what it's called right now and I don't see it written down in my code, but the installer generates a Wizard that installs the program to whatever file you choose.

I make use of a directory system, and I chose this to preserve that structure as easily as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see from the tags you are using C#. Visual Studio can create Setup projects for these kind of tasks. The setup projects als contain a property RemovePreviousVersion, which will remove a previous version if the versioning of your setup is correct and the GUID of the application stays the same.

See this link for more information:
http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/updates-to-setup-projects/

Comment: The screenshot on that link looks just like my installer, so you must be on the right track.  I'll have to read through that guide.  Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

[ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28VS.80%29.aspx) deployment is a great solution most of the time...

You can deploy to the web and when ever your users start the application it will check for updates and automatically update the application if there is a new version available.

It can also be configured not to update automatically but only to notify the user that there is a new version available and allow the user to control the update process.

Comment: I don't have a server set up, so I don't think that will work, but thanks for the info.  I'll file this away under "Some Day, I Wish."  :)